# How to call struct fields from c++ to c#?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli

Well, I am intended to apply Marshalling between managed and unmanaged codes. That is, to retrieve the result from a c++ code to c# code. I am not intended to know the definitions of managed or unmanaged here, rather am willing to find out the proper way of doing so.

Section: Unmanaged code
File: unmanaged_operation.cpp

```
#pragma managed(push, off)

typedef struct _IOperation
{
    double  stOutput;
    double* dblPtrValue;
    BSTR*   parseValue;
    BSTR*   evenValue;
    BSTR*   oddValue;
    BSTR*   stripValue;
    BSTR*   contextValue;
    BSTR*   rangeValue;
} IOperation, *LPIOperation;

#pragma managed(pop)

#if (_MANAGED == 1) || (_M_CEE == 1)
#include <vcclr.h>
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
#endif

// In unmanaged_operation.h file
extern __declspec(dllexport) LPIOperation operation;

// In unmanaged_operation.cpp file
__declspec(dllexport) LPIFactory factory =  new IFactory();

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall Parse(/* in */ BSTR* input)
{
    BSTR* value = Do_Something_With_BSTR_Input_Value(input);

    String^ _output = gcnew String(*value);
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal::StringToBSTR(_output);
    operation->parseValue = (BSTR*)ptr.ToPointer();
    Marshal::FreeBSTR(ptr);
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall Strip(/* in */ BSTR* input)
{
    BSTR* value = Do_Something_With_BSTR_Input_Value(input);

    String^ _output = gcnew String(*value);
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal::StringToBSTR(_output);
    operation->stripValue = (BSTR*)ptr.ToPointer();
    Marshal::FreeBSTR(ptr);
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall Range(/* in */ BSTR* input)
{
    BSTR* value = Do_Something_With_BSTR_Input_Value(input);

    String^ _output = gcnew String(*value);
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal::StringToBSTR(_output);
    operation->rangeValue = (BSTR*)ptr.ToPointer();
    Marshal::FreeBSTR(ptr);
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall Operate(/* in */ double input)
{
    double output = Do_Something_With_Double_Input_Value(input);

    operation->stOutput = output;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) LPIOperation GetOperation()
{
    return operation;
}
```

Section: Managed code
File: managed_operation.cs

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct IOperation
{
    /* MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)] */
    public double stOutput;
    public double[] dblPtrValue;
    /* MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] */
    public string parseValue;
};

Class Program
{
    [DllImport(@"unmanaged_operation.dll"), CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern void Parse([In] String input);

    [DllImport(@"unmanaged_operation.dll"), CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern void Strip([In] String input);

    [DllImport(@"unmanaged_operation.dll"), CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern void Range([In] String input);

    [DllImport(@"unmanaged_operation.dll"), CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern void Operate([In] Double input);

    [DllImport(@"unmanaged_operation.dll"), CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetOperation();

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            IOperation operation = new IOperation();

            Parse("The parse value.");
            Strip("The strip value.");
            Range("The range value.");
            Operate((double)2.45);

            IntPtr ptr = GetOperation();

            // The following line throws the exception

            operation = (IOperation)(Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(IOperation)));

            // The above line throws the exception

            Console.WriteLine("{0}", operation.parseValue);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", operation.stOutput);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
            // Exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' was thrown.
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say that the Do_Something_With_BSTR_Input_Value method in unmanaged_operation.cpp be:

```
BSTR* __stdcall Do_Something_With_BSTR_Input_Value(/* in */ BSTR* input)
{
    return input;
}
```

only for testing purpose, rather the original cited. And I wanted to print the same value to Console, that I passed as a parameter in Parse, Strip or Range method in managed_operation.cs

I used the following code for testing purpose in unmanaged_operation.cpp:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void GetOperationPtr(LPIOperation output)
{
    operation->stOutput = (double)2;
    operation->parseValue = (BSTR*)"The BSTR string";

    *output = *operation;

    // OR output = operation;
}
```

And used the following code in managed_operation.cs

```
[DllImport(@"unmanaged_operation.dll"), CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern void GetOperationPtr([Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct] out IntPtr ptr);

[STAThread]
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        IOperation operation = new IOperation();

        Parse("The parse value.");
        Strip("The strip value.");
        Range("The range value.");
        Operate((double)7.45);

        IntPtr ptr;
        GetOperationPtr(ptr);

        // The following line throws the exception

        operation = (IOperation)(Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(IOperation)));

        // The above line throws the exception

        Console.WriteLine("{0}", operation.parseValue);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", operation.stOutput);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
        // Cannot marshal 'parameter #1': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination
        // (Int/UInt must be paired with SysInt or SysUInt).
    }
}
```

Again I changed the IntPtr to object in GetOperationPtr definition as follows:

```
[DllImport(@"unmanaged_operation.dll"), CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern void GetOperationPtr([Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct] out object ptr);
```

and in the Main method:

```
Object ptr;
GetOperationPtr(ptr);
```

which caused the application terminated instantly without being executed further.

Again when I omitted the MarshalAs attribute from the GetOperationPtr definition, the parseValue
returns garbage value something like 䕃洭獥慳敧 or 옧ﺧ㲨Ѹ㲨Ѹ or 멄攓�ѵ�ѵ rather any visible result.

To get rid of this I added the Charset parameter to DllImport attribute for GetOperation definition, as:

```
[DllImport(@"unmanaged_operation.dll"), CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern IntPtr GetOperation();
```

and used the same code in Main method as described earlier; which in such case shuffled the output value for each instance of IOperation field, as:

```
operation.parseValue returned "The strip value." for the method Parse("The parse value.");
operation.stripValue returned "The range value." for the method Strip("The strip value.");
operation.rangeValue returned "The parse value." for the method Range("The range value.");
```

Any suggestion with code example will highly be solicited.

Answer (score 1):

## Overall

It appears that your goal here is to call some C++ code from C#. In that case, it is generally better to write a C++/CLI managed class (keywords `public ref class`), and call the C++ code directly from there. You can access the managed class from C# in the normal way, just add a .Net reference and instantiate the class with C# `new`.

### Specific issues

```
BSTR* value = Do_Something_With_BSTR_Input_Value(input);

String^ _output = gcnew String(*value);
IntPtr ptr = Marshal::StringToBSTR(_output);
operation->parseValue = (BSTR*)ptr.ToPointer();
Marshal::FreeBSTR(ptr);
```

If you're accessing a managed type (`String^`), it's not unmanaged code.

The way you're assigning the string is incorrect. You're allocating a new `BSTR` object in `StringToBSTR`, saving a pointer to it, and then freeing the `BSTR` object. You now have a pointer to deallocated/invalid memory! That memory can be re-used for anything at any time.

```
public struct IOperation
```

Don't start things with `I` unless they're an interface. That's the naming convention, stick with it.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct IOperation
{
    /* MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)] */
    public double stOutput;
    public double[] dblPtrValue;
    /* MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] */
    public string parseValue;
};
```

If you're copying from unmanaged to managed, how big is the array of doubles? Which of the *multitude* of string representations is it supposed to use?

## Recommendation

I recommend one of two things:

1. If you're interfacing to an unmanaged library which you are the author, consider changing that struct to be something easier to have the automatic marshaller deal with.
2. If you're not the author of the unmanaged library, or if you have other reasons for the struct to look like that, or if you just don't want to deal with the automatic marshaller, then do the marshalling manually: Write a C++/CLI managed class (`public ref class`) that takes the managed struct as a parameter, manually converts everything to the unmanaged struct, calls the unmanaged functions, and then copies everything back.